# Rescaling of a Riemmannian metric

Tags: differential-geometry

I have an issue with an exercise that concerns the behaviour of Riemannian metrics under rescaling.

[image]

My issue lies with b). The curvature tensor can be represented in local coordinates as

$$
\tilde{R}^s_{ijk}=\partial_i (\tilde{\Gamma}^s_{jk})
+\sum_l \tilde{\Gamma}^l_{jk} \tilde{\Gamma}^s_{il}
-\partial_j (\tilde{\Gamma}^s_{ik})
-\sum_l \tilde{\Gamma}^l_{ik} \tilde{\Gamma}^s_{jl}. 
$$

For the Christoffel Symbols I have found that $\tilde{\Gamma}^k_{ij}=\lambda \Gamma^k_{ij}$. So an application of the product rule yields

$$
\tilde{R}^s_{ijk}
=\lambda 
(\partial_i (\Gamma^s_{jk})
+\lambda \sum_l \Gamma^l_{jk} \Gamma^s_{il}
-\partial_j (\Gamma^s_{ik})
- \lambda \sum_l \tilde{\Gamma}^l_{ik} \Gamma^s_{jl})
$$

I am dissatisfied with this result as I would have expected that there would be some sort of relation between $\tilde{R}^s_{ijk}$ and $R^s_{ijk}$. So I am wondering whether there is an error in this.

\Edit: The Christoffel symbols can be computed with the Christoffel formula

$$
\tilde{\Gamma}^k_{ij}
=\frac{1}{2} (\partial_i \tilde{g}(\partial_j, \partial_k))
+\partial_j \tilde{g}(\partial_k, \partial_i) 
-\partial_k \tilde{g}(\partial_i,\partial_j))
$$

Since $\lambda$ is a constant factor, we have

$$
\partial_i \tilde{g}(\partial_j, \partial_k)
=\lambda \partial_i g(\partial_j, \partial_k) 
$$

and analogously for the other summands. So $\tilde{\Gamma}^k_{ij}=\lambda \Gamma^k_{ij}$.

Comment: How do you conclude that the Christoffel symbols transform in this way?

Comment: Just to clarify: $\lambda$ is a scalar function or a *constant*?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin $\lambda$ is a constant. For clarification I have also added my computations for the Christoffel symbols.

Comment: You are confusing Christoffel symbols of the 1st and 2nd kind, this is the origin of your mistake.

Comment: Your formula for $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\tilde \nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connection for $(M,\tilde g)$. Using the definition of the LC connection on a Riemannian manifold as the unique affine connection that is **compatible with the metric** and **symmetric,**  this suggests we look at these relations for  $(\tilde \nabla,\tilde g)$ more closely. By the definition of metric compatibility, we have
\begin{align*}
\tilde\nabla \tilde g(X,Y) &= \tilde g(\tilde\nabla X,Y) + \tilde g(X,\tilde\nabla Y),\\
\text{hence} \quad \lambda \big[\tilde\nabla g(X,Y)\big] &= \lambda \big[ g(\tilde\nabla X,Y) + g(X,\tilde\nabla Y)\big],\\
\text{therefore,} \quad \tilde\nabla g(X,Y) &=  g(\tilde\nabla X,Y) + g(X,\tilde\nabla Y).
\end{align*}
Thus we see $\tilde\nabla$ is compatible with $g$. Since $\tilde \nabla$ is symmetric by definition, we see that $\tilde\nabla$ satisfies the defining properties of the LC connection $\nabla$ for $(M,g)$, and hence $$\tilde \nabla = \nabla.$$

Comment: For @OP: note that this implies that the (1,3) curvature tensor is invariant under rescaling but that the (0,4) curvature tensor scales exactly as does the metric.